# How to remount /sdcard directory to read/write on emulator?

Tags: java, android

Can you please tell me how to remount /sdcard directory to read/write on emulator?

I read [this](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html)

But I don't know how to apply that to remount /sdcard directory in read-write mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/sdcard` directory already is read/write, assuming you have a valid SD card image attached to your emulator.